# deploying laravel to AWS git, run own composer

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to to deploy my laravel app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using git push.
I can successfully deploy laravel app, but my problem is that I had some configuration in my composer.json

I created a config file in .ebextensions

```
commands:
   01updateComposer:
      command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

option_settings:
   - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
     option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
     value: /root
```

How can I configure it to run my own composer.json which I had configured myself in the root of my laravel file.

The configuration above didn't run my composer.json

Thank you.

Comment: What do you see in the environment log? Have you tried to execute the command on the instance itself?

Comment: environment log everything success. Im actually adding autoload file in my composer.json. So I'm actually getting class not found when i access the domain.

Comment: So in the log you see the command being executed, yet you don't see the expected results?

Comment: "Im actually adding autoload file in my composer.json" — Not clear what this means. Can you explain? If you're getting "class not found" when you access the domain, it sounds like Composer _might_ be working, but maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by referring to this

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521843/aws-elastic-beanstalk-and-composer)

replace my command in config with this

```
container_commands:
  01-install-composer:
    command: "curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php"
  02-install-packages:
    command: "php composer.phar install"
    cwd: "/var/app/ondeck"
```

the previous one is success, but my class isn't added to autoload

with the new command, it actually run my own composer.json file and added my class into the autoload file.