# Fatal error class not found on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel

My Laravel 3.2.14 application works locally.  When I upload it to my server I get this:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Tue May 06 07:35:55.995408 2014] [:error] [pid 25701] [client 174.31.190.151:57098] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\LaravelRequest' not found in /var/app/current/laravel/core.php on line 157
[Tue May 06 07:35:56.184608 2014] [:error] [pid 25703] [client 174.31.190.151:57099] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\LaravelRequest' not found in /var/app/current/laravel/core.php on line 157
[Tue May 06 07:40:11.514372 2014] [:error] [pid 25705] [client 174.31.190.151:57103] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\LaravelRequest' not found in /var/app/current/laravel/core.php on line 157
[Tue May 06 07:40:11.704632 2014] [:error] [pid 25706] [client 174.31.190.151:57104] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\LaravelRequest' not found in /var/app/current/laravel/core.php on line 157
[Tue May 06 10:18:36.676282 2014] [:error] [pid 25707] [client 185.4.227.194:40880] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\LaravelRequest' not found in /var/app/current/laravel/core.php on line 157
[Tue May 06 10:54:08.718764 2014] [:error] [pid 25701] [client 115.239.248.56:4697] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\LaravelRequest' not found in /var/app/current/laravel/core.php on line 157
[Tue May 06 13:39:02.024516 2014] [:error] [pid 25703] [client 173.244.215.194:56452] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\LaravelRequest' not found in /var/app/current/laravel/core.php on line 157
[Tue May 06 13:47:31.401996 2014] [:error] [pid 25705] [client 122.226.223.83:4460] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\LaravelRequest' not found in /var/app/current/laravel/core.php on line 157
```

Is this a problem with my composer autoload file?  I get no other inclination of what's happening. I've been working on this for two days and not sure where to go from here :/

Comment: Can we have more informations on how you upload your project on the server ? FTP ? Git pull ?

Comment: @tseho I run `git aws.push` which uploads my changes to AWS.

Comment: I don't know Laravel but most of the time, when you use composer, there is a .gitignore file which ignore your vendors. So, if you push, git will ignore all the files in vendors. This is why you have this error.

Comment: @Tseho Playing with that right now.

Comment: I just read that AWS Beanstalk has Composer. You should try this to install composer dependencies : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17528576/1671377

And you must NOT add vendors/ to your .gitignore.

Comment: @Tseho Thank you! That did it.  I don't understand though I've had vendor/ in my `.gitignore` for a long time and recently had reinit my local git repo and then it does this?

Comment: @Tseho Add an answer to this question I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vendor/` files are not included when you push to AWS Beanstalk because they're ignored by your `.gitignore` file.

You need to include in your git project your `composer.json` and `composer.lock` to send them on AWS Beanstalk on each update.

You can run composer to install the dependencies with a configuration like explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17528576/1671377

Comment: On a side not I also needed to add a environment variable called PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS with a value of --no-dev and then it worked perfectly.

Comment: Also I had to change a folder from `cache/` > `/cache` in my gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

I know the comments below your question have told you take `vendor/` out of your `.gitignore`, but that isn't normal practice. Elastic Beanstalk for PHP actually supports Composer and will automatically run `composer install` on your project when you are pushing a new version.

For this to work, the root of your repo should be the root of the app. You should also have  `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files enabled by your `.gitignore` so that when they are pushed, EB knows to download and install your packages.

Comment: I didn't say to take `vendor/` out of the .gitignore. I was explaining why the vendor were not pushed with the rest of the application. And I find after what to do.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't being pushed with the rest of the application because it was in the `.gitignore`. However, EB will run Composer for you, so it's better to just push up your `composer.lock` (which has all the dependencies locked at the version you're working on) and the same environment will be installed for you.