# Add Composer dependencies to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mailgun, twilio-php

I am migrating an application from EC2 to Elastic Beanstalk and am struggling to install Composer dependencies (Mailgun, Twilio, etc.) across my EB servers.

I am able to install dependencies to single EC2 instances through SSH, but now that I am migrating everything to EB I do not know how to have the composer dependencies installed across all newly scaled instances.

Thank you!

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17528576/161628?

Comment: That explains installing Composer, but that is already installed on the EB instances. I am asking how to add dependencies to Composer across all EB instances.

Comment: If you have a composer.json file (https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) in the root directory of your application source then EB will automatically install the dependencies for you from the file. Additionally, found a nice blog post here: http://blog.goforyt.com/laravel-aws-elastic-beanstalk-dev-guide/